# google script: transform multiline string into one line string with commas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell with multiple lines in it like this:

```
Albert
Jason
Falco
```

and I need to transform it to

```
Albert,Jason,Falco
```

I know how to do it as Excel formula on the sheet but I surely would prefer a scripting solution.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need script? The formula is simple: `=join(",",split(A1,char(10)))`

Comment: I do not want to add new rows. I need to replace the lines like these and use the one-line-version further in the script

Comment: What have you tried already in GAS? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Simon,
I didn't succeed with your suggestion.

But the solution I eventually used was regEx:

```
var t = Sheet.getRange('a1').getValue()
var output = t.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all values are in the "A" column:

```
var rowvalues = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[insert id here]").getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var thestringyouwant = ([].concat.apply([], rowvalues)).join();
```